# Uploading large files to azure blob

Tags: c#, .net, azure, c#-4.0, azure-blob-storage

I am making use of the following program for uploading large files to azure blob storage.
When uploading a small file less than 500KB , the program works fine otherwise
I am getting an error in the following line:

**blob.PutBlock(blockIdBase64, stream, null);**
as "*An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.*"

There is no details about the exception so I am not sure whats the problem . Is there any suggestion regarding what could be the wrong thing in the program below:

```
class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    string accountName = "newstg";
    string accountKey = "fFB86xx5jbCj1A3dC41HtuIZwvDwLnXg==";
    // list of all uploaded block ids. need for commiting them at the end
    var blockIdList = new List<string>();
    StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
    CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    　
    　
    CloudBlobContainer sampleContainer = client.GetContainerReference("newcontainer2");
    string fileName = @"C:\sample.pptx";
    CloudBlockBlob blob = sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("APictureFile6");

    using (var file = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
    int blockSize = 1;
    // block counter
    var blockId = 0;
    // open file
    while (file.Position < file.Length)
    {
    // calculate buffer size (blockSize in KB) 
    var bufferSize = blockSize * 1024 < file.Length - file.Position ? blockSize * 1024 : file.Length - file.Position;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    // read data to buffer
    file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    // save data to memory stream and put to storage
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
    {
    // set stream position to start
    stream.Position = 0;
    // convert block id to Base64 Encoded string 
    var blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
    blob.PutBlock(blockIdBase64, stream, null);
    blockIdList.Add(blockIdBase64);
    // increase block id
    blockId++;
    }
    }
    file.Close();
    }
    blob.PutBlockList(blockIdList);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using the low level PutBlock API anyway? The Azure libraries have easier ways of uploading data.

Comment: @usr : Can you please suggest me any library which makes use of stream  and possibly chunking instead of buffer to avoid memory problems?

Comment: Google for "Azure .NET upload file". This is a solved problem.

Comment: If you just use UploadBlobFromFile you can even just pass the filename in directly. That will do all chunking and file reads for you and avoid a lot of this code.

Answer (score 5):

You're getting this error because your block ids are not of same length. So for 1st 9 blocks your block id length is 1 character but as soon as you reach 10th block your block id length becomes 2. Please do something like the following:

```
var blockIdBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId.ToString("d6", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
```

This way all your block ids are 6 characters long.

For more details, please read `URI Parameters` section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135726.aspx.